# Mock 2 Objects of the same generic class

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a generic class and I want to to Mock 2 different type of objects from this class in order to use in my test.

here is My sample class :

```java
public class A<T> {
   T field;

   // getters, setters , etc...

}
```

and another class like this:

```java
public class B {
   A<String> a1;
   A<Long> a2;

   // Constructors

   // getters, setters , etc...

}
```

now I have a test class which I want to mock 2 objects from this class. something like this :

```java
class Test {
   @Mock
   private A<String> a1;

   @Mock
   private A<Long> a2;

   @InjectMocks
   private B b;


   // tests

}
```

the problem I have encountered is that Mockito will create same mock object for both a1 and a2 and this will result in failure in my tests. I need 2 different mock object(with respect to their generic type of course!)

My attempts :

if I write something like this it will work properly:

```java
class Test {
   @Test
   void test1(){
   A<String> a1 = Mockito.mock(A.class);
   A<Long> a2 = Mockito.mock(A.class);

   B b = new B(a1 , a2);

   // rest of the test...
   }

}
```

but is there any way to just declare a1 and a2 as class fields with @Mock annotation(like the code Block I mentioned before) without any problems and get 2 different mock objects ? ( I have read some related or similar question on stackoverflow, but none of them was useful for me :(  )

P.s : I am using Junit with Mocktio.

Comment: What failure do you get? What makes you think that Mockito has "created the same mock object"?